# AfNetworking download is not successful if phone sleep or a call comes

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to download 4 video files, each one is approximately 50MB, using AfNetworking. I added this block to handle background download operation:

```
[weakSelf.downloadOperation setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    // Handle iOS shutting you down (possibly make a note of where you
    // stopped so you can resume later)
}];
```

When it is downloading, if a call comes, or the phone goes standby mode, file seems to be downloaded, but actually it is not fully downloaded. So the app cannot open the downloaded video file. What should I do for that?

Comment: Did you register your app to run in background?

Comment: No, should I register?

Comment: Any advice about how to do it?